# Is there a word for the shape "Biconcave Disk With Flattened Center"?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

As the title says. Basically the shape of a red blood cell. Does this shape have a name other than biconcave disk with flattened center?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, it is quite specific. I don't know everything, but I think it is up to you to define it, give it a name, and make peolpe use it. You can come up with something fancy, like "redcelloïd" or "bicondiskoïd".

Comment: In South India a sweet, edible preparation of such shape out of milk and sugar is called  "palakova".